# Extracting a cell value (constant row and column number) from multiple files and create a new file

Tags: windows, ubuntu, awk

I have 1344 ascii files with 3 columns and 68 rows of numerical values (no text/strings). They do not have any header, and the columns are space delimited.
I want to extract the value at 2nd column and 7th row from each one of those files, to create one file with one column and 1344 rows.

```
Example file 1:
0.11 3.1450 0.03
0.12 3.1210 0.04
0.13 3.1500 0.02
0.14 3.1530 0.03
0.15 3.1720 0.02
0.16 3.1170 0.04
0.17 3.1220 0.02
...

Example file 2:
0.11 3.1150 0.03
0.12 3.1410 0.04
0.13 3.2300 0.02
0.14 3.1230 0.03
0.15 3.3720 0.02
0.16 3.1370 0.02
0.17 3.2510 0.04
...

Output file:
3.1220
3.2510
...
```

I tried the following code:

`awk '{for (i=7) {getline}; print NR,$2}' *`

It gives me an error that the term is not recognised.

Comment: That's not PowerShell.  ... regardless of that ... [Please do post images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)! Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for a powershell solution or why is the tag there?

Comment: I just removed the powershell tag, sorry, new here. I tried the above code in command prompt as well, but it showed the same error.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but perhaps `awk 'FNR==7 {print $2}' *`?

Comment: Don't post links or images, post a [mcve] that includes concise, textual sample input and expected output that demonstrate your requirements and we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: I realise my mistake in asking the question and have now removed the images and file link.

Comment: Please do add the missing sample input and expected output that we could copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a small set of data for demonstration purposes:

```
$ head f1 f2 f3
==> f1 <==
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

==> f2 <==
a b c
d e f
g h i

==> f3 <==
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

One `awk` idea to extract the 2nd column from the 2nd row in each file:

```
$ awk 'FNR==2 { print $2; nextfile }' f1 f2 f3
5
e
E
```

Where:

- `FNR==2` - if this is the 2nd record of a file
- `print $2` - print 2nd column
- `nextfile` - cease processing current file and begin processing next file

For OP's requirement we replace `2` with `7`:

```
awk 'FNR==7 { print $2; nextfile }' *
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found another solution in matlab and posting the script here, in case anyone else needs it in future:

```
dts = tabularTextDatastore('file location');
files = dts.Files;
data = zeros(1344,1);
for i = 1:1:length(files)
    file_i = load(files{i});
    data(i) = file_i(7,2);
end
```